# Enable/Disable an SWT Text based on a combo selection

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a Text and a combo widgets and i have a selection listener for combo :

```
class MyDialog extends org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog
{
    private Text text;
    private Combo combo; 

public void createDialogArea(Composite parent)
{
    text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);

    combo = new Combo(composite, SWT.NONE);

    combo.add("One");
    combo.add("Two");
    combo.add("Three");
    combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
        {
            if(combo.getText().equals("One");
            {
                text.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } 
    });
}
}
```

But inside selection listener i get a null pointer exception at "text.setEnabled(this);"
text and cobmo are my class fields.

please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: There is no way you can compile the above code without `combo` and `text` being declared final, If you declare them so then there is no way you can get NPE. Please provide a snippet of working copy of your code or excerpt from stacktrace

Comment: those are not final , those are my class fileds. 
class MyCode
{
private Combo combo;
private Text text;

Comment: Yes i did the same now, but the thing is i have this code inside overridden method "createDialogArea" of org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog class, so text and combo gets instantiated when once the dialog is loaded. When we click on combo and select one that is when the listener gets called.
I still dont get your idea.

Comment: The only way you get NullPointerException there is if you set text to `null` elsewhere in your code. Do you have some clean-up routine called prematurely?

Comment: I have a working copy of your program which works perfect as per your expectations, http://pastebin.com/1HeNNQ5H, There should be something wrong in the code at your end.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are getting a null pointer exception at `text.setEnabled(this);`, but the statement `text.setEnabled(this);` does not appear in your posted code.  Only, `text.setEnabled(false);` appears in your posted code.  So, either the error is elsewhere, or your post may need to be revised.